# LayoutConstraints Error when separator for UITableView is removed

Tags: ios, uitableview, nslayoutconstraint

This is my current view:

[image: Main View]

As soon as I try and remove the line seperator from the **UITableView** if throws an error that is: **Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints**

But, to test the same that the error is not due to redundant constraints the result still remains the same.

The error for the same goes of when the line seperator for the **UITableView** is set back to default again

**Console O/P**:

[image: Console O/P]

**Main View Hierarchy**:

[image: Main View Hierarchy]

As it is visible there are no constraints applied to the current view

Comment: Can you briefly explain what are the constraints of a UITableviewcell?

Comment: Where is your line separator and how are you removing it? What were the constraints added on it?

Comment: @Rikh I have disabled the line separator in the UITableView using the Interface Builder. Left, Top, Right and Bottom constraints were applied to the UITableView initially. But I removed them to try and understand what is causing the error

Comment: @Poles Please check comment. Additionally, there are no constraints currently applied

Comment: @SupratikMajumdar : if you have not applied any constraints on the UITableView and the UITableViewCell then you should disable the Autolayout option from File Inspector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried remove all the auto-layout constraints from the view and still the error remained.

The only way to keep no separator lines visible and to not have any **LayoutConstraints** is to set the colour of the separator lines to clear colour

This is possibly a Xcode bug

Comment: What if I don't want to disable separator? Is there a way to fix it?